# Can I generate an INSERT statement in SQL Server 2008 with the selected values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

If I am selecting a whole row from the Results pane of the SQL Server Management Studio 2008, is there a way to create an INSERT statement script automatically that can INSERT a new row with the selected row's values?

Idea is, when I delete that row, I can use the generated INSERT statement to re-insert the same row again.

Basically instead of creating a blank INSERT, create a script with `VALUES (val1,val2,val3...)` where the values comes from the selected row.

Comment: I don't think so ... probably ask Microsoft to add this feature in next release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this isn't possible.

Closest thing to this that I am aware of is the SSMS Tools Pack Addin ["Script Grid Results"](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features#GIS) feature.

This will generate `INSERT` statements to a `#temp` table for the whole results grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger that will insert deleted or updated row into other table you created as backup table, so you always can re-insert specific row back to original table.

Simple, you need some way to backup your affected data.